# globally declare $ or jQuery in angular 2/4

Tags: angular

I am using jQuery in my angular 4 project. In every file I am declaring it on the top. I use this in most of my .ts files

```
declare const $: any;
```

Is there any way I can declare it in a single place and use it in all files, instead of declaring in every file?

Comment: To be honest I can't see why you need jQuery with Angular at all.

Comment: Perhaps back then (Angular 4 times) this may have been needed in some cases. Nowadays however, JQuery should not be used in Angular apps in my opinion, just to make the world a better place.

Answer (score 4):

The better way of using JQuery in Angular is importing its `.d.ts` file, and using `declare const $: any;` is not the a good way since your IDE won't give you auto-completion and can run into some problems

Steps to use JQuery in Angular:

1- Find JQuery (or any other package you want) from [TypeSeach](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/), then you will end up on this [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery), install it:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

2- Install JQuery itself:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

3- Anywhere you want to use JQuery, just Import type declaration file (`.d.ts`) into Angular app:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

**[Read more on this article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af)**

When working with scripts that extend other libraries, for instance with JQuery plugins (e.g, `$('.test').myPlugin();`), since the installed `@types/jquery` may not include `myPlugin`, you would need to add an interface like the one below in `src/typings.d.ts`.

```
interface JQuery {
  myPlugin(options?: any): any;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked in some pages. But at some places, I am using 'jquery-slimscroll' plugin. When I remove declare from there, it's giving me this error: "Property 'slimScroll' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'."